# Third-party Python library specifies call sequence that seems not to work

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to get to work a Python library wrapper on a Spark extension:
[https://github.com/G-Research/spark-extension/][1]

It specifies a **diff** command, which is what I want; the specification is like this:

```
class Differ:
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    Differ class to diff two Datasets. See Differ.of(…) for details.  

    def diff(self: DataFrame, other: DataFrame, *id_columns: str) -> DataFrame:
```

I've tried several options:

```
Differ.diff(one, two)
diff(one, two)
one.diff(two)
```

The first one gives:
`TypeError: diff() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'`

The second one gives

`TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable`

The third one gives

`TypeError: diff() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'`

Docs are sketchy and focused on Scala; I read the code for the specs above. Doc is here: https://github.com/G-Research/spark-extension/blob/master/DIFF.md

Thanks much for any help at all!

Comment: What does "not working" look like? What do the docs say?

Comment: Main question edited to respond to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Your first error is simply trying to call a method on an uninitialised class.  Your second looks like an attempt to call a module. Your third call is the only one which resembles the docs (or makes sense), but since you haven't told us what `one` and `two` are it's impossible to know what it's trying to do.  There's an example on that docs page: try that *exactly* as it is first